# create a div empty to put a border

Tags: html, css

I want to put a border grey of type dotted after each input. So far it works.
[image]

The border grey has as div form_padding_border but it is empty in my html.
Is it correct to do that ?

```
<div class="form_padding">
     <label>Your Username:</label>
     <input type="text" name="username" class="form_group">
</div>

<div class="form_padding_border"></div>

    <div class="form_padding">
    <label>Your Email Adress:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email_adress" class="form_group">
</div>
```

Comment: if it works then it's *correct* but if you are asking if it's the *best* way to do it then the answer is opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form_padding css class, it's better that **you use the border-bottom property**. I've also added line-height on mine for the top and bottom spacing.

```
.form_padding{
  border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

Run the code below for the example.

```css
h2 {
  color: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

.form_padding {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<h2>ACCOUNT INFORMATION</h2>
<label>Please write down your Username, Password, Pin Code,Security Question, and Security Answer as a reminder before creating account.</label>

<div class="form_padding">
  <label>Your Username:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" class="form_group">
</div>

<div class="form_padding">
  <label>Your Email Adress:</label>
  <input type="email" name="email_adress" class="form_group">
</div>
```

Comment: Sure, No problem :D